# Vectorial product to find cosine

Tags: vectors

We have A(2,1), O(0,0), B(0,3) and C(2,4). OACB is a parallelogram. Find the cosine of $\angle AOB$

I know that the cosine of an angle determined by two vectors can be written as $$cos\left(\vec{j}\:\:and\:\vec{p\:}\right)=\frac{\left(\vec{j}\cdot \vec{p\:}\right)}{\left|\vec{j}\right|\cdot \left|\vec{p\:}\right|}$$
I've calculated the length of $\vec{OA}\:and\:\vec{OB}$ but how do I calculate their product(the numerator of the fraction)?

Comment: If you've learned about the dot product you should know how to compute the dot product of two vectors from their coefficients. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Application_to_the_cosine_law

Comment: Well I know that $\vec{j}=a\vec{x}+b\vec{y}$ and I know how to compute the product of two vectors written like this. But how can I write $\vec{OA}$ in this form?

Comment: Just subtract the coordinates of $O$ from the coordinates of $A$ to get the coefficients of $\vec{OA}$. So $\vec{OA} = 2\vec{x}+1\vec{y}$, and $\vec{OB} = 0\vec{x}+3\vec{y}$

Comment: Yes, I did that now. I got the value of the cosine to be $\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}$. Is this correct?

Comment: It looks good to me.